# Hit the curb and scraped my tire; I have no idea if it’s bad/unsafe damage or not

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage, scratch

I was driving in my neighborhood, probably only about 10mph but I accidentally wasn’t paying attention and hit the curb. I pretty much drove into it sideways, but it wasn’t very high impact I don’t even think I had my foot on the gas pedal. Anyway, my tire has a scrape on it now with some peeling. Im a new driver so I have no idea what is considered dangerous or not. [image]

Comment: need to see more detail of the damage - otherwise I suggest replace...

Comment: It looks like it's just the rim protection bit, so it should be okay, but I'd want to see close-up photo before deciding.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've really cut into the rim protection part of the tyre there, as mentioned we can't actually see the damage underneath the torn rubber section in the picture, but if its deep which it looks like it may be towards the thicker end of the tear, then I'd have the tyre replaced.

Answer (score -1):

It's not dangerous, but it very well might leak air.  Check the tire pressure regularly.

Answer (score -1):

It is obvious sidewall damage. Tire can blow out at highway speeds. Replace tire. Risk is not worth it.